# Using Netbeans with Cygwin and SDL, including SDL.h creates strange error

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, cygwin, sdl

I've got Netbeans C/C++ set up, Cygwin installed, configured and running correctly. SDL was installed from the sources using the Cygwin terminal. I've confirmed that Cygwin, Netbeans and SDL are all running correctly, I can write and compile C++ projects just fine with Netbeans and Netbeans can see SDL without having to include any files or anything, it just works like the default libraries.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sdl2/SDL.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

That's the code I'm trying to compile, Netbeans doesn't highlight the include for sdl.h, but when I go to build I get this:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Cally/Projects/Test'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/test.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Cally/Projects/Test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/test build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.30-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.30-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39:(.text.startup+0x7e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/test.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/test.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Cally/Projects/Test'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Cally/Projects/Test'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

The build is successful when I don't include SDL. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*The error message looks really evil - but it just tells you it can't find a `WinMain`.*

This is a known issue with SDL. Please add those libraries to your linker (*order is mandatory!*):

1. `mingw32`
2. `SDLmain`
3. `SDL`

You can either add `-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL` to linker options or add them through the library menu of linker config.

It's possible you need `SDL_mixer` too - if so, just add it last.

Please see also: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials%3aSetup

---

As a *"dirty workaround"* you can do this: undefine `main`.

SDL redefines `main()` as a macro with some additional stuff. You can verify this by egl. *Ctrl + click* on main / go to *declaration / definition* or check if it's formatted as makro.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sdl2/SDL.h>
using namespace std;

/*
 * If 'main' is defined we clear that definition
 * to get our default 'main' function back.
 */
#ifdef main
# undef main
#endif /* main */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

Please see source of [`SDL_main.h`](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f061a86fbb08/include/SDL_main.h) (line 103+).

Comment: These are .a files, right? If so, I can't find any of them.

Comment: Not necessarily, it's also possible that they are dll / so. Maybe their name start with `lib` - the linker adds that automatically.